# Form not submitting correct value from datatable

Tags: php, html, forms, post, datatable

Looks simple but may be I am overlooking something here.

```js
(document).ready(function(){
            $('#data').dataTable();
  }
```

```
if (isset ($_POST ['deleteUser'])) 
{ 
  echo "<p>Received the form data</p>"; 
  echo $_POST['hidden']; 
}

<form action="" method="post">
<table id="data">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>First Name</td>
      <td>Delete Name</td>
      <td>Email</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <?php 
      $cursor=$collection->find (); 
      foreach ( $cursor as $document ) {
      ?>
      <tr>
        <td class='First_Name'>
          <?php echo $document [ "First_Name"]; ?>
        </td>
        <td class='Last_Name'>
          <?php echo $document [ "Last_Name"]; ?>
        </td>
        <td class='Email'>
          <?php echo $document [ "Email"]; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="hidden" name=hidden value='<?php echo $document ["First_Name"]; ?>'>
          <input type="submit" value="Delete" name="deleteUser">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <?php }?>
  </tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

Here I am trying to send the value from the table to the php code on the same page. 
When I click on delete, It always sends in the First name of the last row. 
What is causing the form to submit only the last row when the Button is clicked?
How can I pass the value of the hidden tag for the row in which delete button was clicked on?

FYI :  I have enabled DataTable for the table.

Comment: Are you sure you have name=hidden instead of name="hidden" in your form? If your answer is yes, then change name=hidden to name="hidden"

Comment: Questions or issues with answer?

Comment: Tried changing the name=hidden to name="hidden".
No luck :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form is located in the wrong place so you only have one form with all the users in it. Try this which will give you a form for each user.

```
<table id="data">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>First Name</td>
      <td>Delete Name</td>
      <td>Email</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <?php 
      $cursor=$collection->find (); 
      foreach ( $cursor as $document ) {
      ?>
<form action="" method="post">
      <tr>
        <td class='First_Name'>
          <?php echo $document [ "First_Name"]; ?>
        </td>
        <td class='Last_Name'>
          <?php echo $document [ "Last_Name"]; ?>
        </td>
        <td class='Email'>
          <?php echo $document [ "Email"]; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="hidden" name=hidden value='<?php echo $document ["First_Name"]; ?>'>
          <input type="submit" value="Delete" name="deleteUser">
        </td>
      </tr>
</form>
      <?php }?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Also note deleting user(s) by first name sounds dangerous to me. I'd delete by `id` or `email`.

Function example of what your current script does, so you have `abc123.php` and submit to it as a `GET` with `?a=1&a=2&a=3&a=4&a=5`. You won't get `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, and `5` because they all have the same name. Each iteration overwrites the previous so if `print_r($_GET);` were run `Array ( [a] => 5 )` would be outputted.

Comment: Thanks @chris85 for the suggestions.
I have tried this before, the form doesn't get submitted if I place the form tags between the <tbody></tbody> tags. Any thoughts?


Also, I am not deleting the user based on the First name, this was just an example.